# TFTP server running on virtual machine not responding

Tags: server, virtualbox, ftp, tftp

I'm running TFTP server on a Ubuntu virtual machine(VM Virtual Box), using `tftpd-hpa` package. When I try to connect to a server on my local machine as a client and try running `get` or `put` command, I get `Transfer timed out` message. 10.0.2.15 is and IP address on my virtual machine. Example:

```
local@DESKTOP-GE94PQ9:~$ tftp 10.0.2.15
tftp> get text.txt
Transfer timed out.
```

Server side should be working perfectly fine, since I'm manage to get and put files when I run both server and client on a same machine. The problem is presumably in connecting on server that's running on virtual machine.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to connect to the VM using the computer that is also running the VM (the host) or are you using a different computer?

Comment: @mchid I'm using my local machine, not VM for client side.

Comment: Is the local machine also running Ubuntu? If so, what version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @mchid I have Windows on a local machine, also I'm using WSL with Ubuntu. None of them could get/put files on TFTP server running on a VM. 
I've installed Tftpd64, application that includes TFTP server. It's working perfectly well now, with client running on local machine as well as on VM. 
https://pjo2.github.io/tftpd64/

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?